# Not able to send mail through smtp.gmail.com

Tags: smtp

I want to send mail through "telnet smtp.gmail.com 25" but an error is prompted when sending  a message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first".

I am working on Ubuntu Linux Server. I googled out, and installed ssmtp and tried to add a few lines in ssmtp.conf file so that I could send mail through telnet.

> UseSTARTTLS=YES

But, since the file is read only and also I am not able to change the user rights, Permission Denied. Since I am the administrator of my own system, how can I edit the file and add few lines of code in it?

Also, please tell me whether these techniques will work for me, or any other useful technique available where I can send mails by telnetting.

Thanks..

Comment: Is this related to system administration in some way?

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu you need to use *sudo* when modifying the files.  The account you use isn't running with administrator privileges.

Comment: How can i do that.. Some steps would be useful. Thanks..

Comment: @RBA: you would do something like this 'sudo nano ssmtp.conf' it would then prompt you for YOUR password. That will escalate your privileges and allow you to edit your conf file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send or receive mail from gmail's servers without a valid SSL certificate. [This guide](http://download.gna.org/hpr/fetchmail/FAQ/gmail-pop-howto.html) explains the steps involved.

Comment: Ok,, Is there any other Server,, which can allow me to send mail through smtp telnetting.. Thanks.

Comment: Try using your ISP's mail server.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of an SMTP server you personally own and administer, you shouldn't be telnetting to port 25 to send mail - it looks spammy.

I'm presuming that you're just trying to figure out how SMTP works, or perhaps implementing a mail client - but you should try this against your own server, and not one somebody else runs :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to send email through gmail servers, you need to use **secure SMTP**, which does not sit on port 25. According to the **google [help](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) page**, you need to connect to either port 465 of 587 for secure SMTP over SSL/TLS. If you want to test it out using telnet, either use `telnet-ssl` or `openssl client` to test the connections.